# Modifying PostGIS database using geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I want to build a mobile app using `GeoServer` and `PostGIS` database and I am little confused about how user will interact with database.

I want end users to be able to upload new geospatial data to the database (not from any map view but from a formula). In order to be able to upload data, user shall first sign in (or log in).
Each data will be associated to the user id.

Do I need to create a web service to handle accounts creation and database modification (wrapping `SQL` query) or can I directly use `GeoServer`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using Geoserver. Geoserver supports Transactional WFS:

> The Web Feature Service (WFS) is a standard created by the Open
>   Geospatial Consortium (OGC) for creating, modifying and exchanging
>   vector format geographic information on the Internet using HTTP.
>   (Source: Geoserver WFS reference)

You are probably best served with having a separate user model and integrate your code as a client (user) towards geoserver. The data you deposit could carry a reference to your user model id.

You could of course also interact directly with the database. Depends, amongst many things, on how you harvest your spatial data from the users, if you prefer to keep your database unavailable from your client side code and more.